# How to group strings based on one of their substring?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text, nlp

I have the following list `jargs`.

```py
jargs = ['10192393\t15\t26\tskin tumour\tDiseaseClass\tD012878', 
         '10192393\t443\t449\tcancer\tDiseaseClass\tD009369',
         '10192393\t483\t496\tcolon cancers\tDiseaseClass\tD003110',
         '10194428\t30\t45\themochromatosis\tModifier\tD016399',
         '10194428\t102\t117\themochromatosis\tSpecificDisease\tD006432',
         '10194428\t119\t145\tHereditary hemochromatosis\tSpecificDisease\tD006432',
         '10194428\t147\t149\tHH\tDiseaseClass\tD006432']
```

I want to write a program that outputs the following:

```py
ents = 
[
'10192393', {"entities":[(15, 26,"DiseaseClass"), (443, 449, "DiseaseClass"), (483, 496, "DiseaseClass")]}, 
'10194428', {"entities": [(30, 45, "Modifier"), (102, 117, "SpecificDisease"), (119, 145, "SpecificDisease"), (147, 149, "DiseaseClass")]}
]
```

I tried the following:

```py
ents = [list(set([jargs[i].split('\t')[0] for i in range(len(jargs))]))[0],\
       {"entities": [(int(jargs[i].split('\t')[1]), int(jargs[i].split('\t')[2]),\
       jargs[i].split('\t')[-2]) for i in range(len(jargs))]}]
```

Unfortunately, this code outputs the following

```py
['10194428',
 {'entities': [('15', '26', 'DiseaseClass'),
   ('443', '449', 'DiseaseClass'),
   ('483', '496', 'DiseaseClass'),
   ('30', '45', 'Modifier'),
   ('102', '117', 'SpecificDisease'),
   ('119', '145', 'SpecificDisease'),
   ('147', '149', 'DiseaseClass')]}]
```

Which is not the output expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pprint import pprint

tmp = {}
for item in jargs:
    id_, v1, v2, _, v3, *_ = item.split("\t")
    tmp.setdefault(id_, []).append((v1, v2, v3))

ents = []
for k, v in tmp.items():
    ents.append(k)
    ents.append({"entities": v})

pprint(ents)
```

Prints:

```py
['10192393',
 {'entities': [('15', '26', 'DiseaseClass'),
               ('443', '449', 'DiseaseClass'),
               ('483', '496', 'DiseaseClass')]},
 '10194428',
 {'entities': [('30', '45', 'Modifier'),
               ('102', '117', 'SpecificDisease'),
               ('119', '145', 'SpecificDisease'),
               ('147', '149', 'DiseaseClass')]}]
```

Comment: I was going to post exactly this. A few clear loops are better than forcing a hot mess in a comprehension list and you also don't get to repeat yourself with `jargs.split('\t')`.

Comment: Perhaps consider `from collections import defaultdict`?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel That's an alternative too - depends on personal preference. For simple tasks like these I just use `dict.setdefault`.